# resetting Rails database without restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, server, reset

Is there a way to reset the database in a Rails app WITHOUT restarting the server?

Actually, is it a stupid thing to do?

<sub>(I suspect it is)</sub>
 <sub>(I already tried to send some requests while doing migrations. The migrations failed and the whole db was corrupted, so maybe I can see where this is going, but some more insight can be helpful and interesting)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

try `rails db:reset` if you use rails 5 or `rake db:reset` for resetting db.
`rails db:drop` for drop database

Comment: The running server won't like that, not one bit.